# How to save a list data in .NET C# and SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm so confused about Lists in .NET. I know it is not possible to save a List in database.

I have a User class and an Offer class that contains a list of Comments, I want an offer to be able to have several comments and the same thing for User and I want to save the data on my database in order to bring comments data associated to my Users/Offers when I fetch /GET.

But I don't know how can I save the Comments Id List and associate it to Users or Offers.

My classes and methods:

```
public class Offer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Comment>> PostComment(Comment comment)
{
    var existingOffer = await _context.Offers.FindAsync(comment.OfferId);

    if (existingOffer == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("This Offer Does Not Exists");
    }

    existingOffer.Comments.Add(comment);
    _context.Comments.Add(comment);

    var existingUser = await _context.Users.FindAsync(comment.UserId);

    if (existingUser == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("This User Does Not Exists");
    }

    existingUser.Comments.Add(comment);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetComment", new { id = comment.Id }, comment);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Offer>> PostOffer(Offer offer)
{
    ...

    _context.Offers.Add(offer);

    offer.Comments = new List<Comment>();

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Retornar a resposta
    return CreatedAtAction("GetOffer", new { id = offer.Id }, offer);
}
```

Comment: SSMS is a DBA tool, not a database or something you can use through C#. The code you posted uses *Entity Framework*, an ORM that persists any changes you make to the objects it tracks to a database. It will persist changes to all *related* objects as well, so when you call `SaveChanges` all the changes will be persisted in a single transaction

Comment: In this case what's the problem? What `Comments Id List` are you talking about? EF itself will save any changes made to `Offer.Comments` or any of the comments in that list. You don't need a separate list of those IDs. You don't need `offer.Comments = new List<Comment>();` either - Comments is an empty list already

Comment: The `Id` properties in both Offer and Comment will be updated by EF itself after it saves the changes. You can even omit them and use `Comment.Offer` and `Comment.User` properties instead, while `User` can have a `Comments` property.